# Can I delete these docker images?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

When I run this command: `docker image` it lists a lot images named `none' unknown to me:

[image]

And it seems to take a lot of storage. Can I remove them?

Comment: `docker image prune`

Comment: `docker system prune` also. Browse the documentation a bit for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prune command helps you. It removes all dangling (unreferenced) images (none:none)

Command:

```
docker image prune
```